# Why do I get an error when using - to substract an int in a println statement?

Tags: java

I am facing an error in the following program at the last print statement, but I don't know the exact reason behind it.

Please let me know the reason for the error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int c,d;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the first number : ");
        c = s.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the second number : ");
        d = s.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("The sub is : "+ c-d);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: In future, if you're going to ask about an error, *please* say what the error is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
System.out.println("The sub is : "+ (c-d));
```

instead of

```
System.out.println("The sub is : "+ c-d);
```

and check if its working now.

Answer (score 5):

You need parentheses around the subtraction:

```
System.out.println("The sub is : " + (c - d));
```

This is because without parentheses, the `+` and `-` operators have the same priority and associate left-to-right. So the compiler tries to parse it as if it were written:

```
System.out.println(("The sub is : " + c) - d);
```

The first part is okay and is an expression that produces a `String` result. Unfortunately, there is then no way to apply the `-` operator to an expression where the left side is a `String` and the right side is an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

that's because, you are trying to do string concatenation, as your first operand is a string.

try this:

```
System.out.println("The sub is : "+ (c-d));
```

notice that (c-d) in brackets.

compiler would complain that `-` operator is un-defined for string and int.

> The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int

Note that the `Sub is:+ c` the result would be a string. now

```
`Sub is:+ c` - d;
^^String     - int
```

Comment: Yeah I know that its used for concatenation in java but why its giving error in the case of - ?

Comment: @ShivamChopra because as it concatenates the first two operands with `+` as `-` operator doesn't work in case of string compiler complains